# SQL: Return first non null value from the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Problem : I want to retrieve the first non null value from the string, substring is separated with , as separator.

Scenario :

String 1 - ,1002682657

String 2 -  1002682683,

String 3 - ,,1002682684

String 4 - ,,,

String 5 - 1002682664,1002682663

### Expected Result

ResultString 1 - 1002682657

ResultString 2 - 1002682683

ResultString 3 - 1002682684

ResultString 4 - null value

ResultString 5 - 1002682664

So to retrieve this I wrote function below is the script

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Return_first_NonNull_Value_From_list]
(
    @List NvarChar(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVarChar
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @ReturnListPart NvarChar(max)
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
DECLARE @Length_String INT

SET @Start = 1
SET @End = CHARINDEX(',',@List,@Start) 
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
SET @Length_String= (@END-@Start)+1

SET @pos = 0
SET @nextpos = 1

WHILE @Start>0 and @End>0 and @Length_String>0
    BEGIN
        IF (SUBSTRING(@List, @Start, 1) <> '') AND (SUBSTRING(@List, @Start,2) <>'')
            BEGIN                   
                SET @ReturnListPart = SUBSTRING(@List,@Start,@Length)
                SET @Length_String= LEN(@ReturnListPart)
                IF @Length_String > 1
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Length_String =0
                    END
            END

        ELSE
            BEGIN
            -- Replace the string with null value if null
                SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(STUFF(@List,@Start,@Length,'')))
                SET @Length_String = LEN(@List)
            END             
    END

RETURN RTRIM(LTRIM(@ReturnListPart))

END
```

But this function doesn't return the expected result. Could anyone please help me out in this?

Comment: As string splitters go the while loop approach is the absolute slowest way you can use. Here is an article with a handful of far better alternatives. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Once you do that you have to realize you don't have any NULLs in there. You have empty strings which is NOT the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Sean Lange. I tried something different approach for this used XML with cross apply for splitting the string.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/04/21/sql-server-split-comma-separated-list-without-using-a-function/

Comment: LOL. If you had looked at the article I sent you would have found a nearly identical XML style splitter in there too. :D

Answer (score 0):

With two assumptions from your question you could do this pretty easily. It looks like your numbers are all 10 characters long, and they only have numerics (no characters).

With this in mind you could just do this with a pattern match like so:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Value] LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN SUBSTRING([Value], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Value]), 10)
         ELSE NULL
       END [Value]
  FROM [#Test]
```

We can discount any rows without numeric characters straight away and return null, the rest we look for the first numeric character and get the next 10 chars.

A full sample to run in sql server would be:

```
CREATE TABLE [#Test]
(
  [Value] NVARCHAR(1000)
)

INSERT INTO [#Test] ( [Value] ) VALUES  ( N',1002682657')
INSERT INTO [#Test] ( [Value] ) VALUES  ( N'1002682683,')
INSERT INTO [#Test] ( [Value] ) VALUES  ( N',,1002682684')
INSERT INTO [#Test] ( [Value] ) VALUES  ( N',,,')
INSERT INTO [#Test] ( [Value] ) VALUES  ( N',1002682664,1002682663')

SELECT CASE WHEN [Value] LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN SUBSTRING([Value], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Value]), 10)
         ELSE NULL
       END [Value]
FROM [#Test]

DROP TABLE [#Test]
```